# immediate="true" and required fields problem

Tags: jsf

I'm having a little trouble with immediate="true" (JSF 1.2). My form is about a car accident: the user fills in some ubication information and then he can add as many affected items as he wishes (trees, fences, other cars, etc.)

**Backing bean**

```
private String location;
private List<T> items;
private HtmlDataTable itemsUI;

public void remove(ActionEvent e) {
    String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    items.remove(Integer.parseInt(id));
}   

public void add(ActionEvent e) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    items.add(element.newInstance());
}
```

**JSPX**

```
<h:inputText 
required="true"
value="#{ACC01.location}"/>

<h:dataTable
binding="#{ACC01.itemsUI }"
value="#{ACC01.items}"
var="item">
<h:column>
    <h:selectOneMenu
    value="#{item.id}>
        <f:selectItems  
        value="#{ACC01.possibleElements}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandLink 
    actionListener="#{ACC01.remove }"
    value="Remove"  >
        <f:param 
        name="id" 
        value="#{ACC01.itemsUI.rowIndex }"/>
    </h:commandLink>    
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>

<h:commandLink 
actionListener="#{ACC01.add}"
value="Add"  />
```

**The problem**

- If I set immediate="true" for the affected elements in the dataTable, when the user adds a new element the other elements return to their default values (e.g. if you had {'tree', 'car', 'fence'} they become {'default', 'default', 'default', new element})
- If I don't use immediate, the affected elements keep the right values, but the user is forced to fill in the 'location' field before he can add or remove affected elements.

What I want is to be able to keep the affected elements' values and allow the user to add or remove them without having to fill the 'location' field first.

**The workaround**

After reading many posts about this topic, it seems that the only way to go is to avoid automatic validation and make it manually when the user submits the form.

Check for nulls on required fields, and programatically appending the error messages to facescontext. I really do not want to do that because i think it is ugly.

Can you please suggest better ways to achieve the behavior i need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the previous developers at my current job came up with the following solution

JSPX

```
<h:inputText required="#{ACC01.saving}" value="#{ACC01.location}"/>
```

Backing Bean

```
private UICommand btn;

public boolean isSaving()
{
    Map<?,?> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return (params.containsKey(btn.getClientId(ctx)));
}
```

It might not be totally correct in your situation, but basically he created a binding from the button on screen to the 'btn' variable in the backing bean. Then inputText would only see the location text being required when the btn was clicked. In your case it's a command link so it might be a little different but I thought it might help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, sounds like less work to do and still is a functional solution.

Comment: actually, i didn't have to change anything, the snippet works fine as it is. Thanks again Kartik.